# .NET SQL connectivity - from remote machine

Tags: .net, sql-server

Need you help on an issue. I have a VB.NET application, in which I am trying to connect to a DB - fairly simple.

The connection string passed is `Data Source=<servername>;Initial Catalog=<DB name>;Integrated Security=True`. To check the validity of the connection , I use `mDB.Connection.ConnectionString` - mDB is of type `DataClassDataContext`. Now,when I try to run this from a local server, the connection to the DB is established.

However, I copy this exe to a server outside the continent and run it from there and the DB connection fails. I get this value for the connection string as returned from the server - `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` .

Here is where it gets weird, someone from the other side can execute the same exe, but if he tries to run this exe from the American server, he faces the same issue. I can see clearly that this is not an exception, but the connection is simply refused (also does not time-out. )

Please help ..

Comment: Is your server configured for remote access and the logins that you are trying (your domain and username) are defined as trusted in that server?

Comment: too little information.  My best guess is the connection is attempting to resolve by name and DNS has no knowledge of the name, or the IP you're trying to access isn't rotatable, or the firewalls inbetween don't have the correct ports open.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that this can be a problem with your firewall.

If you have console access to the server which is having problems, run Telnet:

```
telnet servername 1433
```

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23704/easy-way-to-check-connectivity-to-sql-server-from-client

Comment: Being able to telnet to a port doesn't mean that you can connect using integrated security.

Answer (score 0):

I put an udl file in remote server's shared path and put in the server and DB names and this could connect. However, the code does not seem to connect.

The code being used is very simple - 
Try
            If pubSQL.ValidServer("server Name", "DB name") Then
                pubSQL.OpenServer("server Name", "DB name")
            Else

```
            MsgBox("Unable to connect to DB")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception : ok = False
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return ok
```

While I run this from the local American server -I'm able to connect, however I copy the same exe to a European server and the DB connection fails. My counterpart runs the same exe on the European server and this works and fails if he runs it off the American server. 
I hope my explanation helps.